# Just a little error in my fuction general_poly

Tags: python

Hello everybody I almost correct with my code and here it is:

```
def general_poly (L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value 
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """

    def inner(x):
        L.reverse()
        return sum(e*x**L.index(e) for e in L)
    return inner
```

but gives an error when I test 4 should give 189 but give me 18

Thanks

Comment: Please add you exact test input.

Comment: `when I test 4 should give 189 but give me 18` But what is the input you gave for `L`?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would recommend against using `L.reverse()` because it will modify your list in-place, causing difficult to track down bugs. You probably want `return sum(e*x**L.index(e) for e in reversed(L))` instead. Or make a local copy of `L` and reverse that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing `inner`

There are a couple things in your method that should be cleaned up. First of all, when you call `L.reverse()`, you are actually reversing the list that is referenced by the variable passed into `general_poly`. You should use `reversed` which is an iterable, copy of the original list, reversed.

```
def general_poly(L):
    """ ... """

    def inner(x):
        enum_iter = enumerate(reversed(L))
        return sum(e * pow(x, i) for i, e in enum_iter)
    return inner
```

Also, you'll see that I've wrapped the `reversed(L)` call in `enumerate` which returns tuples containing the index **and** the element in the given iterable value. This means you don't need to use the `L.index()` method in ever loop iteration, saving you lookup time. Also, personally I prefer using `pow` over the `**` syntax because I think it reads a little more clearly, *but that is just my preference*.

### Testing `general_poly`

Let's use an example to test this. If I generate a poly function with `[1, 2, 3]` it should return a function representing the equation `x^2 + 2x + 3`.

```
func = general_poly([1, 2, 3])
print(func(3))  # 18
print(func(4))  # 27
print(func(5))  # 38
```

Comment: Thanks men, you really help me.